# CakePHP 3 : show associated data along with find('all')

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.2

I'm working on CakePHP 3.2. I have two tables `categories` and `subcategories` where `subcategories` is associated with `categories` with foreign key `category_id`.

I have to build a drop down navigation using these two tables. So that It will look like this

```
-Menu
|- Category_1
   |- Category_1_subcategory_1
   |- Category_1_subcategory_2
   |- Category_1_subcategory_3
|- Category_2
   |- Category_2_subcategory_1
   |- Category_2_subcategory_2
|- etc
```

For this this is what I have done.
In `AppController.php`

```
// set navigation menu
$this->loadModel('Categories');
$menu_categories = $this->Categories->find('all', [
  'contain' => ['Subcategories'],
]);
$this->set('menu_categories', $menu_categories);
```

Then in `navigation.ctp`

```
$foreach($menu_categories as $menu_category):
   echo $menu_category->title;
   foreach($menu_category->Subcategories as $subcategory):
      echo $subcategory->title;
   endforeach;
endforeach;
```

But this prints only `category->title` and not `subcategories`

I have to print subcategories under each belonging category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to define the associations in the models.

Category Model:

```
$this->hasMany(
   'Subcategory', [
        'className' => 'Subcategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
]);
```

Subcategory Model:

```
$this->belongsTo(
   'Category', [
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your navigation.ctp snippet,

```
echo $menu_cateory->title;
```

Also, make sure you've correctly set `$containedModels` in Categories, that you've correctly set the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` associations in Categories and Subcategories, and that you've correctly included the `Containable` behavior.

Comment: what is error in `echo $menu_category->title`. Categories table contains `title` column which I'm printing. and this is printing well

Comment: In your snippet you wrote "$menu_cateory", it's missing the letter g. If that's the code directly from your source file then something else is printing it because that is certainly a syntax error. The main point of my comment however is to make sure that you are correctly associating your models.

Comment: ohh, sorry, The code was not directly from source. It was typed and was just a typing error.